# Storing Hexa-decimal Values

Tags: java, hex

I have an sequence of 30 or so hexa decimal values 0x01, 0x02...
My question is how can i store these values in Java. I do not know if it matters to convert it into String and store it. But thats what i am not looking for. I just want to store the hexa decimal as constant data. Please also consider the contents representing the Hex-Decimal form and if/what happens to it ?

Comment: This is not clear.  Is `final static int[] MY_VALS = { 0x1, 0x2, ... };` what you need?

Comment: yes, it looks like what i need as the values will also remain constant in this case , please correct me if i am wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hexadecimal is just a format to display numbers, just like decimal, binary or octal. Numbers are just numbers - hexadecimal is not a property of the numbers themselves, it's only a way to display numbers.

Writing the numbers as `0x01`, `0x02`, etc. in your source code is exactly the same as writing them in decimal `1`, `2` etc.

So, you can store the numbers like you would store any other numbers - for example as an array of `int`s.

Answer (score 2):

You should store them as `Integer`s using the [Integer.valueOf(String s, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method.

In your case, the radix is 16.

Answer (score 0):

Just store them in an integer (if it fits within the value range) ... when displaying them, convert it as hex.